# Specifying a key for datastore entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm still trying to get my head around how the datastore works. I don't have previous experience with databases, so it's not a conflicting paradigm situation; I think I'm just confused about NDB's ancestor structure.

Let's say I have this model class:

```
class Spam(Model.ndb)
    eggs = ndb.StringProperty();
```

So I create an instance and store it like this:

```
foo = Spam(eggs="some string")
foo.put()
```

I understand that `put()` returns a key that I could easily call `get()` on if I'm trying to access it from the same script, but is there a way to specify my own key, so I can easily access the `foo` entity from another script in my app?

I realize I can specify a parent for `foo` like this:

```
foo = Spam(parent=ndb.Key("Bar","Baz"),eggs="some string")
```

But from there, how would I use `"Bar"` and/or `"Baz"` to access `foo` in a different script?

Comment: Firstly, please pick a more relevant title for your question: this is about specifying a key, and has nothing to do with "other scripts". Secondly, have you read the [documentation on keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities)? That seems quite clear about how you would specify your own key.

Comment: I changed the title to be more descriptive.

It does have to do with "other scripts" in that my goal is to `put()` an entity in one script and `get()` it in another.

I did read the key documentation, but its description of the interface wasn't very clear, so I came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parents are used if you have a hierarchy. So if you have recipe books you would put the book as the parent and each recipe as a child. I don't think that's what you want.

If you want to set the key do this:

```
SuperEggs= Spam(id='SuperEggs', eggs="2 egg whites")
SuperEggs.put()
```

You can always let App engine set its own keys, this will prevent contention and accidental over rides, when you want access to the entity again simply do a get on some field. Add a name and search that.

FYI the returned id from the put lets you access from any part of your app (or any authorized app). The datastore is global not specific to a script.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

I'm aware that the datastore is global; I just wasn't clear about how to `put()` an entity in one script and `get()` it in another without passing around variables between them.